# Toggle Sound effects off

Tags: android

I currently want to disable sound effects for my game, which I toggle on or off in a preferences activity.

```
public static  void initSounds(Context theContext)
    {
        
        if(OptionsMenu.getSounds(theContext))
        {
             mContext = theContext;
             mSoundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
             mSoundPoolMap = new HashMap();
             mAudioManager = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        }
    }
```

When I do this however, the soundeffects don't turn off.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default `SharedPreferences`, you should be able to do it by simply doing something like this:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    nixonMode=prefs.getBoolean("nixonmode", false);
```